# Writing Einstein-Hilbert and Gravity-matter Hamiltonian in terms of creation/annihilation operators

Tags: quantum-field-theory, operators, hamiltonian-formalism, quantum-gravity, qft-in-curved-spacetime

I am trying to understand how to write the gravity-matter and gravity-gravity hamiltonians in terms of daggered/undaggered operators. Is there any pedagogic review paper on writing such hamiltonians in terms of combined annhilation/creation operators with corresponding coefficients.

Answer (score 1):

As a starting point, gravity it's not a quantum theory so there is no annihilation/creation operators for gravity for the moment.
In the approach of canonically quantizing gravity you have to treat gravity as a gauge theory, namely imposing constraints and defining the physical Hilbert space as the states annihilated by the Hamiltonian constraint. To promote the Hamiltonian constraint to an operator you first have to switch to Ashtekar variables, rewrite the constraint in those new variables and then promote those to operators on the Hilbert space. This is the approach used in the Canonical loop quantum gravity quantization, you can find plenty of pedagogical reviews on arxiv, choose the one adeguate to your mathematical taste.